# Standards-compilant way to disable selection via CSS

Tags: html, css, selection

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/826782/399317) is about how to disable selection of DOM elements via user interaction. (This is wildly important for some rich HTML apps like games.)

The most common solution is the `user-select: none` CSS rule (plus its browser-specific variants) which indeed does the trick for now.

However, a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting/4358620#comment17348769_4358620) mentions that this feature was only a draft and isn't present in the current CSS specification.

What's the story here? Was this feature renamed or perhaps was it made obsolete on purpose? Can I count on this feature to remain functional or should I start implementing it differently or avoid it altogether?

Comment: I think it was rejected on the basis that you shouldn't use CSS to modify behavior. Let me scour the mailing lists and see what I can find...

Comment: Use javascript `onselectstart="return false;"` instead

Comment: It seems to have been lost in time (along with the ancient css3-userint draft). Right now, the main issue lies with gross inconsistencies in browser implementations, due in part to the fact that it's not specced anymore (go figure...).

Comment: Also, I would hesitate on calling something a standard even if it's in the "current specification", *unless* the specification is at least a Candidate Recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

This will hide any selections

```
::selection {
    background: transparent;

}
```

Comment: It doesn't "disable" selection *per se*, but it does make the illusion of it.